# user login ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, authentication

The problem is that Roles.IsUserInRole throwing false when i run this code. It should take me to admin page but it redirect me to default page. This is working perfectly on other pages, i am confused. Any Suggestions?

```
@{
    var username = string.Empty;
    var password = string.Empty;
    var errorMessage = string.Empty;

    if (IsPost) {
        username = Request["username"];
        password = Request["password"];

        if (WebSecurity.Login(username, password)) {
            if(Roles.IsUserInRole("admin"))
            {
                Response.Redirect("/Admin/");
            }else{
                Response.Redirect("/");
            }
        } else {
            errorMessage = "Username and/or password is incorrect.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code for your user roles as well ?

Comment: Try using [GetRolesForUser()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ak75t41.aspx) and displaying the results.

Comment: yes Ali i provided that!